# vmware site recovery manager - site A to B and B to A

Tags: vmware-esx, disaster-recovery

I will Need to clarify few faqs on vmware SRM, my situation is, i have 25 VMs in site A, and 5 VMs in site B. I need to protect both sites and should be able fail back site A to B and  B to A, does SRM protect both ways or will have any limitation on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SRM can protect in bidirectional way.

You can have:

25VMs in production in site A  will failover in site B

5VMs in production in site B  will failover in site A

Comment: Cagliostro
Thanks for the response,How to setup bidirectional protection ? do i  need to have two SRM setup ? or two recovery plan ?

Comment: Yep, you need two SRM installations (and two vCenter).
All the job must be duplicated..on site A you need one or more protection groups (it depends on you storage configuration) for the 25 VMs and, at least, one recovery plan for site B.
On site B you need the opposite..one or more protection groups for the 5 VMs and, at least, one recovery plan fore site A.

With this configuration you will be able to start a failover from A to B, from B to A..or both.
The main work (read project design) is based on storage configuration..but this may vary based on your storage server.

Comment: How can i have DR without SRM ? is it possible to have a manual DR plan eliminating SRM ?

Comment: You can have several other way to accomplish a DR implementation (a DR plan is step-by-step procedure to failover/failback your production)...and yes, you can obtain the same DR failover/failback without SRM executing manual steps. If you can describe more in deep how your virtual infrastructure (site A and site B) is actually implemented I can tell you some more details.

Comment: Cagliostro,
Site A&B are in same subnet, A will host 5 esx 40 VMs, 3 esx in cluster, B will host 4 esx with 10 VMs 2 esx in cluster, each site will have own san and we will be replicating site to site considering an RPO/RTO of 24 Hrs.I need to use site A as recovery for Site B, and site B as recovery for site A, in case of a disaster i will be running all vms in one site ( with existing vms + recovered VMs ). addition to this i will need to I will need to have a flexibility to recover ONE or TWO vms for on demand cases ( minor disaster like configuration, user errors ).

Comment: If your storage servers support it, you can mirror LUNs and recover all (or only someone) of your VMs as if you were using SRM..but manually. In macro step you: 1) stop mirror, 2) remap mirrored LUN-target, 3) prepare for production mirrored VMs. But, as for your RTO/RPO needs..instead of SAN mirroring you can use software synchronization like DoubleTake Availability for Virtual Infrastructure or Vizioncore Replicator.

Comment: one more clarification, do i need a dedicated esx in standby mode for each site ? i could configure on an existing esx which hosts one more production vms in both sites ?

Comment: It depends on your 'global' DR configuration..If you choose the right (for your environment and needs) solution, properly configure your SANs and your esx have enough comp resources..yes,you can avoid standby esx.